# How to get the value of textboxes and use it as a filename of an image

Tags: php, html

can somebody help me? I am trying to upload an image to a specific directory using PHP and I want to know how to get the value of a textbox and use it as the image filename. Below is my code.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}


?>
```

Any reply is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP `move_uploaded_file(file, newloc)` have second option as source destination + file name. Like:

```
move_uploaded_file(file, '/var/www/html/project/public'.$filename);
```

here `$filename` is the name of file by which it is moved to your server. You can give any name to the file like time-stamp value or a string given by user.

In your case:

```
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I just want to get the value of textbox and set it to my image filename

Answer (score 0):

What really matters about the target filename is actually the following to lines:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

So, you just need to send the POST request to the PHP like following as you've probably done:

```
<form method="POST" action="target_process.php">
<input type="text" name="filename">
...(other form objects here)
</form>
```

And retrieve the info in the PHP, and append it to the target_file. Also, append the extension type to the end of the file.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$file_parts = explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$ext = $file_parts[count($file_parts) - 1];
$target_file = $target_dir . $_POST['filename'] . '.' . $ext;
```

Comment: how about if I have two textbox?